# Encoded URL in Ktor Client

Tags: kotlin, urlencode, ktor, ktor-client

I need to make a GET request using a Ktor client. The URL I'm using is passed to me as a string from a source I have no control over. The URL string contains commas that are encoded by the Ktor client to `%2C` which is breaking the backend logic. Is there a way to prevent Ktor from encoding the URL?

Example to clarify:

```
client.get {
    url(url)
    accept(ContentType.Application.Json)
    method = HttpMethod.Get
}
```

In the following code, the value of `url` is `https://my.domain/someData,someMoreData` but the outgoing request URL is `https://my.domain/someData%2CsomeMoreData`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent Ktor Client from encoding url parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71130590/how-to-prevent-ktor-client-from-encoding-url-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer, but comments don't allow to post big chunks of code.

After investigating it some more, I actually wasn't able to reproduce the behaviour you're describing:

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
            routing {
                trace {
                    application.log.debug(it.buildText())
                }
                get("*") {
                    context.respond(context.request.path())
                }
            }
        }
        server.start()

        val client = HttpClient()
        val url = "http://localhost:8080/someData,someMoreData"
        val r : String = client.get {
            url(url)
            method = HttpMethod.Get
        }
        println(r) // Getting /someData,someMoreData, meaning not encoded
    }
}
```

This is using `implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:1.2.6"`

What client engine you're using?

Comment: I'm using `Android` engine with `okhttp`. Version `1.2.4`. In the meantime solved it on the server side. Will also try to upgrade to `1.2.6`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the title of this question is basically the opposite of the actual content (which asks how to PREVENT encoding), its a top search hit on using ktor to encode URL parameters.  To do that use:

[fun String.encodeURLParameter(spaceToPlus: Boolean = false): String](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-http/io.ktor.http/encode-u-r-l-parameter.html)

and to encode forms use [formUrlEncode](https://api.ktor.io/ktor-http/io.ktor.http/form-url-encode.html).