# How to prevent Ktor Client from encoding url parameters?

Tags: android, kotlin, download, ktor, ktor-client

I am trying to create an android app with kotlin, this app need to have a mini download manager as I will need to download files from 100MB to 8GB and user can pause and resume download later when the server supports the pause, searching I found the Ktor library and reading the documentation plus some videos on youtube, I managed to write a base code where I could download the files and make the process of stopping the download and keep going all right when one of mine tests gave error there are files whose url pattern is: `http://server.com/files?file=/10/55/file.zip`

The problem is that I put this link, but Ktor converts to `http://server.com/files?file=%2F10%2F55%2Ffile.zip` this generate an error response on the server, as I don't have access to the server to change this rule I need to send the right url without encoding. Does anyone know how to do this? Prevent Ktor from doing a `URL_encode` in the url parameters, I couldn't find anything in the [documentation](https://ktor.io/docs/welcome.html)

My code is this:

ktor-client version 1.6.7

```
fun startDownload(url: String, auth: String = "", userAgentS: String = "", fileName: String = ""){
    val client = HttpClient(CIO)
    val path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val file = File.createTempFile("File", "index", path)

    runBlocking {

                client.get<HttpStatement>(url){
                    headers {
                        append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, auth)
                        append(HttpHeaders.UserAgent, userAgentS)
                        append(HttpHeaders.Range, "bytes=${file.length()}-")
                    }
                }
                    .execute { httpResponse ->
                        val channel: ByteReadChannel = httpResponse.receive()
                        while (!channel.isClosedForRead) {
                            val packet = channel.readRemaining(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE.toLong())
                            while (!packet.isEmpty) {
                                val bytes = packet.readBytes()
                                file.appendBytes(bytes)
                                println("Received ${(file.length())} bytes from ${httpResponse.contentLength()}")
                            }
                        }

                        val pathF = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/${fileName}")
                        file.renameTo(pathF)
                        println("A file saved to ${file.path}")
                    }
            }
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this problem with ktor, if there is no solution, can someone tell me another way to achieve the same goal? Need to be with Kotlin.

update 2022-02-17

Thanks to Aleksei Tirman's help I managed to solve the problem, thank you very much. And the base code looks like this:

```
fun startDownload(url: String, auth: String = "", userAgentS: String = "", fileName: String = ""){
    val client = HttpClient(CIO)
    val path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
    val file = File.createTempFile("File", "index", path)

    runBlocking {

                client.get<HttpStatement>(url){
                    url {
                        parameters.urlEncodingOption = UrlEncodingOption.NO_ENCODING
                }
                    headers {
                        append(HttpHeaders.Authorization, auth)
                        append(HttpHeaders.UserAgent, userAgentS)
                        append(HttpHeaders.Range, "bytes=${file.length()}-")
                    }
                }
                    .execute { httpResponse ->
                        val channel: ByteReadChannel = httpResponse.receive()
                        while (!channel.isClosedForRead) {
                            val packet = channel.readRemaining(DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE.toLong())
                            while (!packet.isEmpty) {
                                val bytes = packet.readBytes()
                                file.appendBytes(bytes)
                                println("Received ${(file.length())} bytes from ${httpResponse.contentLength()}")
                            }
                        }

                        val pathF = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/${fileName}")
                        file.renameTo(pathF)
                        println("A file saved to ${file.path}")
                    }
            }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your question and updated response, for me  httpResponse.contentLength() returns null !! , while file.length() has value. Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Friend I tested the code here and it is working normally, call this function like this to test  startDownload(
            url = "https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.32/VirtualBox-6.1.32-149290-Win.exe",
            fileName = "VirtualBox-6.1.32-149290-Win.exe"
        )  httpResponse.contentLength() is a response from the server, there are some cases where the server does not inform the file size, perhaps the server where you tried to download the file does not pass this information in the header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable query parameters encoding by assigning the `UrlEncodingOption.NO_ENCODING` value to the `urlEncodingOption` property  of the `ParametersBuilder`. Here is an example:

```
val requestBuilder = HttpRequestBuilder()
requestBuilder.url {
    protocol = URLProtocol.HTTP
    host = "httpbin.org"
    path("get")
    parameters.urlEncodingOption = UrlEncodingOption.NO_ENCODING
    parameters.append("file", "/10/55/file.zip")
}

val response = client.get<String>(requestBuilder)
```